# Company title in notification differs from company in inbox

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs

I was recently contacted by a company about a potential job via Stack Overflow. The notification in the inbox notifications was different than the name of the company in the actual inbox.  The initial text in the notification did match that in the inbox. Possible bug?

I can provide a screenshot and the names of the company privately upon request, though I imagine you can also just dig into my data and find it yourself.